# Checking whether a cell of a Dataframe is the last to appear

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe made of multiple columns. My goal is to add an additional field which contains a flag indicating whether the value of a specific column (in this case `col_1`) is the **last** to appear.

Input:

```
   col_1 col_2
0      1     A
1      2     B
2      1     C
3      1     D
4      3     E
```

Desired output:

```
   col_1 col_2  last_row_of_col_1
0      1     A              False
1      2     B               True
2      1     C              False
3      1     D               True
4      3     E               True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with parameter `keep='last'` and inverted mask by `~`:

```
df['last_row_of_col_1'] = ~df.duplicated('col_1', keep='last')
print (df)
   col_1 col_2  last_row_of_col_1
0      1     A              False
1      2     B               True
2      1     C              False
3      1     D               True
4      3     E               True
```

Or compare first values in descending order if equal `0`:

```
df['last_row_of_col_1'] = df.groupby('col_1').cumcount(ascending=False).eq(0)
print (df)
   col_1 col_2  last_row_of_col_1
0      1     A              False
1      2     B               True
2      1     C              False
3      1     D               True
4      3     E               True
```

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I know that reverse `cumcount` is possible with `ascending` parameter. +1